# Blazor NavigationManager go to Location without change Url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a dynamic rewrite mechanism.

In a table that I called Rewrite I store all keys and respectively the page and parameters I have to call.

For example:

| Key | Page | Red | Green | Blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red-products | Products | 255 | 0 | 0 |
| green-products | Products | 0 | 255 | 0 |

In my **Products.razor** page the page directive is

```
@page/{red}/{green}/{blue}
```

and I have

```
    [Parameter]
    public string red{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string green{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string blue{ get; set; }
```

In My **Index.razor** there is the start of this mechanism.

so it has this page directive

```
@page "/"
@page "/{key}"
```

In **Index.razor.cs** I have

```
public partial class Index : BaseComponent
{
    [Parameter]
    public string key { get; set; }
    [Inject] protected HttpClient Http { get; set; }
    [Inject] protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }


    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            Rewrite r = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Rewrite>($"api/Rewrite/GetRewriteByKey/{0}/{key}");
            
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"{r.Page}/{r.Red}/{r.Green}/{r.Blue}");
        }
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is call Product page without changing url in browser, so keep pred-products in browser url but call Products page with parameters 255,0,0.

Is it Possible? or is there a smarter way to handle these rewrites?

In Asp.net web forms I'm using the same reasoning in the file global.asax and I use the command

```
Context.RewritePath($"{r.Page}/{r.Red}/{r.Green}/{r.Blue}");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can use  `DynamicComponent` to manage your *Page*.

The following code should demostrates hoe to use it.

A Data Provider to provide the data - your API call.

```cs
namespace SO77439144.Components.Pages;

public record MyData(string Key, string ClassName, int Red, int Green, int Blue);

public class DataProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<MyData> Items => _items.AsEnumerable();

    public ValueTask<MyData?> GetDataAsync(string key)
        => ValueTask.FromResult( _items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key));
 
    private  List<MyData> _items = new()
    {
        new("red-products", "SO77439144.Components.Pages.Products", 255,0,0),
        new("green-products", "SO77439144.Components.Pages.Products", 0,255,0),
        new("blue-products", "SO77439144.Components.Pages.Products", 0,0,255),
    };
}
```

Registered as a service.

The `Products` component:

```cs
<h3>Products</h3>

<div>
    <pre>Red : @Red</pre>
    <pre>Green : @Green</pre>
    <pre>Blue : @Blue</pre>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int Red { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int Green { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public int Blue { get; set; }
}
```

And Index:

```cs
@page "/"
@page "/key/{Key}"
@using System.Reflection
@inject DataProvider Provider
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.
@if (_componentType is not null)
{
    <DynamicComponent Type="_componentType" Parameters="_componentProperties" />
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Key { get; set; }
    private string? _key;
    private MyData? _data;
    private Dictionary<string, object> _componentProperties => new() {
        {"red", _data?.Red ?? 0},
        {"green", _data?.Green ?? 0},
        {"blue", _data?.Blue ?? 0},
    };
    private Type? _componentType;

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (_key == this.Key)
            return;

        _key = this.Key;

        if (_key is not null)
        {
            _data = await Provider.GetDataAsync(_key);
            _componentType = this.GetComponentType(_data.ClassName);
        }
    }

    private Type? GetComponentType(string className)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var instance =  assembly.CreateInstance(className);
        return instance?.GetType() ?? null;
    }
}
```

Paths are then *https://localhost:7123/key/red-products* etc.

Comment: fantastic solution! It works, thank you very much!